# Help to understand why the sine wave from a curve line is not the same lenth of the curve line?

Tags: mathematics, curve-modifier

[image]

I have problem -Please help me to sole the problem of the length if you can tell me reason i will be gratfull

[image]

Comment: Well now if you think that blender generated modifiers like sin or cos phases and lengths can be understood;  please enlighten me sometime.  But the bottom line is that -- while ESL is difficult -- you'll get little help from what is here.  Put yourself in the place of the helper.  What would she/he ask?  When you helped someone: what information would be valuable (here) to invoke a response?  Avoid emotions; frustrations about the software: 3D modeling and animation is very arcane software.  Click on Edit under your question when you have more information.

Comment: Please share your .blend on https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The solution is quite simple: if you want the sine wave to have the same dimension on X as the straight line, they should both start at the same X value and end at the same X value.

But you are plugging the *Position* **vector** into the **float** X input of the *Combine XYZ* node. A vector $\vec{v}=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ will be converted into a float value by averaging the three values:

$$f(\vec{v})=f(v_1,v_2,v_3) = \frac{v_1+v_2+v_3}{3}.$$

In your case the three components are the $x$, $y$ and $z$ values but since $y,z=0$ this results in

$$f(x,y,z) = \frac{x+y+z}{3} = \frac{x+0+0}{3} = \frac{x}{3}.$$

Which means, while your straight line goes from -7 m to 10.1 m, the resulting sine curve only goes from $\dfrac{-7}{3}\approx -2.3333$ to $\dfrac{10.1}{3}\approx 3.3667$ so it is only one third of the original size.

What you need to do is use a *Separate XYZ* node to get the individual X float values so you can plug them into the X input of the *Combine XYZ* node to keep them the same as before. Oh, and by the way if you do not have a specific reason for the *Transform Geometry* node, you can achieve the same by entering -1.4 as Z value in the *Offset* vector of the *Set Position* node:

[image: separate x values]

The other thing is: I do not know if this is intentionally (but probably not since you did not seem to care for separating the vector), the sine is now also just calculated for the -2.3333 to 3.3667 range. Maybe you want to use the separated X value there as well:

[image: sine of x not averaged]

Comment: Is there any way to use string to show the coordinate of the points of the sine ? -Because in the x  goes from 0 to 5   is  this value are in radiant ?

Comment: @KebabSharif Where does the x go from 0 to 5? The x goes either from -7 to 10.1 or -2.3333 to 3.3667 with the values in your question. The z values as result from $\sin x$ are ranging from -1 to 1 and with the offset from -2.4 to -0.4, but yes - the _Math_ node takes the input as radians, not degrees.